# How can I get so much iron ore?

Tags: eco

I've been playing Eco for a while now and I have come across a resource problem

I am trying to create a factory

To create a factory, I need:

- 6 electric motors
- 30 circuits
- 120 substrates
- 600 fibreglass
- 3000 plastic
- 15000 petroleum
- 15000 barrels
- 75,000 iron ingots
- 375,000 iron ore

Note: To create the one above, you need whats below e.g. to create the iron ingots you need 5x as many iron ore (5 iron ore = 1 iron ingot)

How can I get this many resources?
375,000 iron ore is a lot to get!

Answer (score 1):

[ECO](https://eco.gamepedia.com/) is an MMO based around the concept of survival being balanced by a dynamic ecology.  Your actions can permanently destroy your planet.

Having said that, the point of the same is the first two M - Massive Multiplayer.  If you can easily gather the resources by yourself, there is no point in calling it "multiplayer".

Second, there are [Efficiency Skills](https://eco.gamepedia.com/Skills#Basic_Crafting_Efficiency) that can reduce resource usage by up to 80%.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but even so having a server with 37 people playing (I play with 3 friends on the 1-3 player setting) and with everyone, all 37 people mining, everyone still has to get 10000 iron ore each! You can only carry 20 at a time and this would take over 30 days. Is there any way to get some machinery or something to get more iron ore, or have I messed up and you don't need anywhere as near as much?

Comment: I would imagine that there's tools to get more iron ore in one go, so you need to build tools to get more iron ore so you can build the factory.

Comment: @Kevin_van_der_Velden I know of the excavator, but that's still not enough